# Sample truncated variables in R JAGS?

Tags: r, jags, rjags

I want to use a normal approximation on the posterior distribution of one parameter, which represents a probability. My problem is that simply using `dnorm()` in JAGS model setup will return values outside [0, 1]. I've tried things like `max(dnorm(...), 0)` but it won''t work for this scenario.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this? The R packages I used are `rjags`, `R2jags` and `coda`

Comment: `dnorm` isn’t the usual choice for sampling probabilities. You could use `dbeta` or model the log odds with `dnorm`. If you must use `dnorm` to model probabilities, take a look at JAGS’ `t` (for truncate) function.

Comment: Zhil, use `T(L,U)` where `L` and `U` give the lower and upper truncation limits. So in your case `dnorm(...)T(,0)`. (JAGS ha sgreat user manual https://sourceforge.net/projects/mcmc-jags/files/Manuals/4.x/). (but agree with Limey that (-Inf, 0) limit isn't correct for a probability)

Comment: ... another option is a `logit` link but would need to see your model for more focussed suggestions